# I want my web page to scale down only on Desktop & tablet but not on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

So my website looks great on Desktops having a display resolution of 1920x1080 or higher. It's an e-commerce website so I am having a lot of elements on product pages.

The problem is when viewed on Desktop or Tablets with resolution 1366X768 or less, a lot of these elements doesn't show up so users have to scroll down the page to view those elements. I fear that some users may not even notice these elements and I will potentially lose customers.

So, I thought why not scale down the webpage to around 75% so that all of the elements fit without scrolling and with little googling around I found this CSS code.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1366px) and (max-height: 768px) {
   html {
      zoom: 0.75
   }
}
```

Now it runs great on desktops and tablets and I loved how my webpages just scale down to 75% with all the necessary elements on the screen right in front of the user without requiring them to scroll down the webpage.

But I noticed a huge problem with it when I opened my webpage on mobile. Those were also scaled down to 75% of their original dimensions. I don't want them to scale down on mobile. I need them as is. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this. Its work for ipad to laptop screens. its target the browser screens.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1366px) {
  html {
  zoom: 0.75
 }
}
```

Or you can use this code. max-device-width is the width of the device's entire rendering area. same as height

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 1366px) and (max-device-height: 768px) 
{
  html {
    zoom: 0.75
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use device width/height instead:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 1366px) and (max-device-height: 768px) {
  html {
    zoom: 0.75
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should suffice, zooms in for any screen above 768px in width(ipad and above):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
html {
 zoom:0.75;
 }
}
```